# Reload ActiveRecordCollectionProxy after record creation via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Been trying to implement a like button that will be disabled after create the record via ajax .Below is my code implementation .How do i make the user only able to click once and reload the page and disabled the button?.Current implementation works only when the page is reloaded manually.

My implementation idea :
Load the like association relation user_id array via this line in the view

```
<% if listing.like.collect(&:user_id).include?(current_user.id)%>
```

and verify if the current_user is included in order to display the disabled button.

Models

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many   :like, foreign_key: :listing_id, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to  :listing
  belongs_to  :user
end
```

like Controller

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController  
before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create 
     @like = Like.new(like_params)
     respond_to do|format|
     if@like.save
         current_user.create_activity(@like, "like")
       format.js
     else
        format.html (redirect_to root_url , notice:"Unable to proceed")
        format.js
     end
    end
  end

 [...]

end
```

Views

```
 <%=form_for(Like.new,:remote => true) do |f| %> 
       <%= f.hidden_field :listing_id, value: listing.id %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
       <% if (listing.like.collect(&:user_id).include?(current_user.id)) == true %>
             <%= f.button " " , class: 'round-button btn-center', data:{disabled: true} do %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>    
             <%end%>   
          <%else%>
              <%= f.button " " , class: 'round-button btn-center', data:{disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>"} do %>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>    
             <%end%>
        <%end%>
      <%end%>
```

=>_listing.html.erb

```
<div class="item">
  <%= link_to (image_tag listing.image.url(:medium)), listing_path(listing) %>               
    <div class="info">
      <span class="item_title"><%= listing.name %></span>
        <%if listing.display_usd == true %>
          <span class="item_price"><%=number_to_currency(listing.price, unit:"$", precision: 2)%></span> 
        <% else %>
          <span class="item_price"><%=number_to_currency(listing.price, unit:"HTG", precision: 2)%></span> 
        <%end%>
      <span class="avatar_info">
         <%=link_to seller_path(listing.user.id) do %>
         <%=image_tag listing.user.avatar.url(:athumb), size: "20x20", 
             alt: "avatar",class: "img-circle has-tooltip ",
             title: listing.user.username , 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'top'  %>
         <%end%>
      </span>

    </div>

    <% if listing.created_at >= (Date.today)%>
      <span class="label label-green">New</span>
    <%end%>

  <div class="block-actions clearfix">
    <%= render partial: "likes/form", listing: @listing %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new file `create.js.erb`, in this file you can re-render your form and the content will be updated, eg:

```
$('#your-form-wrapper').html("<%= j render('likes/form') %>");
```

---

Tips: `has_many :like` should be `has_many :likes`, the association should be plural noun.

```
  listing.like.collect(&:user_id).include?(current_user.id) # yours
  listing.like.exists?(user_id: current_user.id) # better performance
```

Answer (score 0):

If your record creating work successfully on your current code and functionality then ok current code for creating the record, now just need some updating this code for show disable button without reloading the whole page.

I don't know what is your view file name, in the view file you can declare an `id` like

```
#=> index.html.erb
<div id="like-form">
   <%= render partial: "likes/form", listing: @listing %>
</div>
```

Now create a `partial` and placed the form inside partial

```
#=> _like_form.html.erb
<%=form_for(Like.new,:remote => true) do |f| %> 
    <%= f.hidden_field :listing_id, value: listing.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <% if (listing.like.collect(&:user_id).include?(current_user.id)) == true %>
         <%= f.button " " , class: 'round-button btn-center', data:{disabled: true} do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>    
         <%end%>   
    <%else%>
        <%= f.button " " , class: 'round-button btn-center', data:{disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>"} do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>    
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now create a `JS` file which named with your view file like if I hold on view file is `index.html.erb` then `JS` file is `index.js.erb`

```
#=> index.js.erb
$("#like-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("likes/form", , listing: @listing)) %>");
```

Now update your controller `create` action

```
def create 
    @like = Like.new(like_params)
    respond_to do|format|
        if @like.save
            current_user.create_activity(@like, "like")
            format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @like, :status => :created, :location => @like }
        else
            format.html (redirect_to request.referer , notice:"Unable to proceed")
        end
    end
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i was trying this approach , but because i'm rendering the form partial in another partial, i'm having problem with the hidden field variable  try to pass it as a local variable like that `$('.block-actions').html("<%= j render :partial => 'likes/form' ,:locals => { :listing => @listing } %>"); `  , but still giving me error.

Comment: Ok, fine you can declare `@listing` variable are both actions and render like see the updated answer, need passing the variable when partial rendering

Comment: well,even passing the local variable through the partial , still not getting the listing value for the hidden field. `undefined local variable or method `listing' for #<#<Class:0x0000000cffa170>:0x0000000cff9180>`

Comment: How you define `@listing` can you put the action code

Comment: in the create action `def create
     @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
     @like = Like.new(like_params)
     respond_to do|format|
    if @like.save
            current_user.create_activity(@like, "like")
            format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @like, :status => :created, :location => @like }
        else
            format.html (redirect_to request.referer , notice:"Unable to proceed")
        end
    end
  end`

Comment: `@listing` variable need to render from `index` action or which action contain this form or result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163568/discussion-between-obed-lorisson-and-fool-dev).